# How to use ^ and $ to parse simple expression?

Tags: python, regex

How do I use the `^` and `$` symbols to parse only `/blog/articles` in the following?

I've created ex3.txt that contains this:

```
/blog/article/1 
/blog/articles 
/blog 
/admin/blog/articles
```

and the regex:

```
^/blog/articles$
```

doesn't appear to work, as in when I type it using 'regetron' ([see learning regex the hard way](http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex7.html)) there is no output on the next line.

This is my exact procedure:

1. At command line in the correct directory, I type: regetron ex3.txt. ex3.txt contains one line with the following:

   /blog/article/1 /blog/articles /blog /admin/blog/articles

although I have tried it with newlines between entries.

1. I type in `^/blog/article/[0-9]$` and nothing is returned on the next line.
2. I try the first solution posted,`^\/blog\/articles$` and nothing is returned.

Thanks in advance SOers!

Comment: What language is your regex being used in?

Comment: which language tool are you using?

Comment: Try this regex: `^\/blog\/articles *$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your update, it sounds like `^` and `$` might not be the right operators for you.  Those match the beginning and end of a line respectively.  If you have multiple strings that you want to match on the same line, then you'll need something more like this:

`(?:^|\s)(\/blog\/articles)(?:$|\s)`

What this does:

```
(?:^|\s)            Matches, but does not capture (?:), a line start (^) OR (|) a whitespace (\s)
(\/blog\/articles)  Matches and captures /blog/articles.
(?:$|\s)            Matches, but does not capture (?:), a line end ($) OR (|) a whitespace (\s)
```

This will work for both cases, but be aware that it will match (but will not capture) up to a single whitespace before and after `/blog/articles`.

Answer (score 5):

Change your regex to:

```
^\/blog\/articles$
```

You need to escape your slashes.

Also, ensure there are no trailing spaces on the end of each line in your `ex3.txt` file.

Comment: Works for me without escaping them: `perl -E'say 1 if "/blog/articles" =~ m[^/blog/articles$]'`.

Comment: Ah, I have not checked the trailing spaces. Will do that ASAP!

Comment: @Quentin It depends on what is parsing the regex. Forward slashes usually mean something in regex (ex: `/hello/gi` to do a global case-insensitive search for the word 'hello')

Comment: @dhsto The slashes aren't part of the regular expression in your example; they are operators that delimit the regular expression 'hello'

Comment: @chepner yeah I know it's technically not. It does make a difference in the actual regex though. For example, try typing in `var test = /^/blog/articles$/gi;` in javascript and you will see you get a syntax error without escaping the slashes.

Comment: @m0skit0 go here: http://regexpal.com/ -- Check off "^$ match at line breaks". Paste in my solution in the top box. Then paste in goldisfine's ex3.txt in the bottom box, but remove the trailing spaces from the end of each line. You will see it matches only "/blog/articles" like what he asked. (on that site you can also not escape the slashes if you wish.. all depends on the language)

Comment: Yeah I read the question wrong... Your answer is correct but still depends on what programming language he's using. In Java for example you don't need to escape slashes.

Comment: @m0skit0 yeah it does all depend. Maybe there's a bug in that regetron shell he's using. It seems like when he runs `regetron ex3.txt` it outputs the file as one line.